# How do you use repaint rectangle and FPS in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I understand that repaint rectangle has something to do with a part of the page being repainted. But why does it stay red, sometimes, after the repaint is over with?

On the FPS bar what does the number at the top right mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the numbers in the top-right corner "5-63" are min and max framerate in the timespan the histogram shows.

Have a look into Addy Osmani's blog post on [improving performance with chrome dev-tools and timeline](http://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/)